# Variable outside the scope of its call/ the variable is not saved, javascript in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Hi all I recently started learning JavaScript. I am working in the visual studio code environment. I am having a bit of some complications with understanding something that is occurring with my code. I began with the the code

```
var faker=require('faker');
```

This was executed successfully. Now I added the following

```
console.log(faker.internet.email());
```

Upon trying to run that single line I get the error that the variable faker is not defined. However if I run the entire file, the file is successfully executed with the desired result.

So it seems that variable is not being saved into my local environment. This seems to be different from my experiences working with c++ and python in visual studio code. Is this an inherent property of java script? Or is this something specific to the way visual studio code deals with java script?

EDIT:
I installed faker using:

```
npm install faker
```

it gave me the following log

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/myuser/package.json'
npm WARN myuser No description
npm WARN myuser No repository field.
npm WARN myuser No README data
npm WARN myuser No license field.

+ faker@5.1.0
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 1 package in 1.522s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

it is giving me the desired output when running the whole file but not individual lines.

the error looks like this:

```
console.log(faker.internet.email());
            ^

ReferenceError: faker is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/Desktop/javascript_code/tempCodeRunnerFile.js:1:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.244 seconds
```

Comment: How exactly did you "run that single line"? Also no, variables are not in any sense saved to the local environment. Don't run single lines. Write a script, then run it.

Comment: I highlighted the line and using the right click I selected run code

Comment: Ok, I've never heard of this. Why would you even want to do that? No matter, just unlearn that as quickly as possible. Also, you should start with `npm init` in your project folder before starting to install modules.

Comment: @ChrisG Ha, I wanted to verify that the particular part was working since I had other code that was commented out and dependent on this. Is this bad practice ?

Comment: Depends I guess, but as you found out, that only works for pieces of code that don't rely on variables defined elsewhere. For smaller programs, just run them in their entirety. And for bigger projects you'd implement unit tests anyway (those are the things you use when you want to test part of a bigger program)

Comment: @ChrisG Gthanks for the tips specially the npm init. I am used to doing unit testing from the command line but not vs code.